# correcto manejo de crontab

Tags: linux, crontab

Mi consulta es la siguiente: tengo que programar 3 respaldos, base de datos, configuración del sistema y logs. en la propuesta los definí de ésta manera, es correcto (va con el comentario para comparen lo que hice con lo que quería hacer)

```
0 0/3 0 0 0 root sh /opt/backups/dbBack.sh #Backup de la BD cada 3 horas.
0 0 0/1 0 0 root sh /opt/backups/logBack.sh #Backup de logs del sistema diario.
0 0 0/1 0 0 root sh /opt/backups/syscfgBack.sh #Backup de configuracion del sistema diario.
```

Aparte aprovecho, como es el proceso para comprimir cada uno de los archivos o directorios que genera cada uno de los scripts, para ahorrar espacio, ya que no tengo idea alguna. Gracias.

Comment: Si pones `0` en weekday sólo se ejecutará en domingo, para cualquier día de la semana debes usar `*`, similarmente para los otros parámetros.

Comment: o sea que si quier cada 3 horas es * */3 * * * ???

Comment: Si pones `*` en minutos, lo correrá cada minuto de cada 3er hora, normalmente se elige el minuto cero: `0 */3 * * *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo como:

```
0 */3 * * * root sh /opt/backups/dbBack.sh #Backup de la BD cada 3 horas.
0 0 * * *  root sh /opt/backups/logBack.sh #Backup de logs del sistema diario a las 12AM (hora 0).
0 1 * * * root sh /opt/backups/syscfgBack.sh #Backup de configuracion del sistema diario a las 1AM para que no corra junto con el de las 12.
```

Si quieres controlar las horas en las que se hace el de cada 3 horas:

```
0 2,5,8,11,14,17,20,23 * * * root sh /opt/backups/dbBack.sh #Backup de la BD cada 3 horas y no corre junto a los otros backups.
```